# Finding value of constant for the CDF of a random var

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ a random var satisfying $\mathbb{E}\left[ X^2 \right] = 10$, with CDF

$$
F(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\ 
a & 0 \leq x < 1 \\ 
0.5 & 1 \leq x < 3 \\ 
0.8 & 3 \leq x < 6 \\ 
1 & 6 \leq x \end{cases}
$$

Evidently, $X$ is discrete and defined over $Im_{X} = \{0, 1, 3, 6\}$. I am interested in finding a value of $a$ that satisfies the constraint pertaning to the expected value. I was able to do this finding the PMF of $X$. Namely, observing that $P(X = x) = F(x) - F(x -
1)$,

$$
\begin{align*}
    f(x) = \begin{cases}
         a & x = 0  \\ 
        .5 - a & x = 1\\ 
        .3    &x = 3 \\ 
        .2 & x=6 \\ 
    \end{cases} & &  x \in Im_X
\end{align*}
$$

We require

$$
\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{Im_{X}} x^2 f(x)   = 10 \\ 
    & 0^2 \times a + 1^2(.5-a) + 3^2(.3) + 6^2(.2) = 10 \\ 
    &.5 - a + 2.7 + 7.2 = 10 \\ 
    & 10.4 - 10 = a \\ 
    & .4 = a
\end{align*}
$$

However, I'm curious in methods that do not use the PMF. Is there a way to find $a$ without recurring to the PMF of $X$?

Comment: No, you need the $\textbf{pmf}$ of $X$.

Comment: $f(x)$ is the Probability Mass Function.

Comment: Corrected the terminological issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: PMF is the best way, but for nonnegative random variables like this you could alternatively use $E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} P[X>x]dx$.

Comment: You can also use the formula $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int (1 - F(x)) \ \mathrm{d}x$ which will give you the same equation as you got. Personally, I would suggest to use the PMF based approach that you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X$ is nonnegative, the *cdf* of $X^2$ which I denote by $G$ is given by $G(x) = 0$ if $x < 0$ and $G(x) = F(\sqrt{x})$ if $x \geqslant 0$. That is:
$$
G(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x < 0 \\ 
a & 0 \leq x < 1 \\ 
0.5 & 1 \leq x < 9 \\ 
0.8 & 9 \leq x < 36 \\ 
1 & 36 \leq x \end{cases}
$$
Since $X^2$ is nonnegative, you can use the formula
$$
E(X^2) = \int_0^\infty P(X^2 > x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty (1-G(x))\,dx.
$$
Hence
$$
E(X^2) = 1\times (1-a) + 8 \times 0.5 + 27 \times 0.2 = -a + 10.4.
$$
And one finds $a = 0.4$.

Alternatively, since $X^2$ is valued in the nonnegative integers, one can use
$$
E(X^2) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \Pr(X^2 > n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigl(1-G(n)\bigr),
$$
but I didn't try this approach.

Comment: This is the kind of approach I was looking for. Thanks